# Why do we work path integral quantization of bosons and fermions in coherent states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, path-integral

I am not able to understand that why it is very special or convenient to work out path integral quantization of bosons and fermions in coherent states. Is it possible to work things in a very general state that could be present in the Hilbert space or any other state (but not coherent state)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use coherent state path integral? What is its motivation or goal?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224329/)

Comment: The answer is not satisfactory I felt...Because I got to know that we can do the same quantization without even using coherent states

Comment: So please help me understanding the basic fact...

Comment: Just a side note. Path integral formulations are usually not suited for monte-carlo simulations, due to the sign problem. In that case, one usually consider instead a formulation using Fock states, which does not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do QFT in any basis, but the coherent state basis is a particular convenient choice.  That's because if you have a normal-ordered second-quantized Hamiltonian of the form
$$H = \int d^3x\, \mathcal{H}(a^\dagger(x), a(x)),$$
then it's very easy to convert it into an equivalent path-integral Lagrangian, which is much easier to deal with, which is simply
$$L = \int d^3x\, \mathcal{L}(\bar{\psi}, \psi), \\
\mathcal{L}(\bar{\psi}, \psi) := \bar{\psi} \partial_\tau \psi - \mathcal{H}(\bar{\psi}, \psi).$$

I.e. just take the function form of $\mathcal{H}$ and replace every $a^\dagger$ with a $\bar{\psi}$ and every $a$ with a $\psi$, where $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ are c-numbers so you no longer need to keep track of their ordering.  Without this universal recipe, for each Hamiltonian you wanted to consider, you'd need to either work in canonical QFT and keep careful track of operator ordering, or to rederive the more convenient Lagrangian equivalent from scratch every time.  You never *need* to work in the coherent state basis, but it's very convenient to do so because the Hamiltonian and Lagrangian densities match up very closely.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the coherent states are used for quantization using the Feynman Integral mostly in undergraduate books on QM. In real applications one usually uses fields in the spacetime coordinate basis, because in this basis Lagrangian is manifestly local and Lorentz invariant. For evaluating amplitudes in the perturbation theory using the Feynman diagrams, it is convenient to work with fields in the momentum space, because in this basis propagator has a mach simpler form, and it is trivial to implement the condition of conservation of momentum.

Comment: I still don't get the idea. Is there any literature which will state this difference in working with non coherent states and coherent states ? can you please tell me the answer

Comment: @user135580 In principle, one can work in any representation -- all of them are correct. In the canonical quantization it is common to work in the coherent state formalism, because it is easy to implement T-ordering. For proving theorems, generalizations of known results, discussion of some general ideas, one usually works in the spacetime basis, in which symmetries, locality and unitarity are manifest. For evaluating cross-sections it is common to work in momentum space, in which the Feynman rules have the simplest form and the momentum conservation is trivially implemented.